# how to display text box when only selected by checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a table which display items of my database beside item name, I displayed checkbox also in table to select the item hence items  are rendering dynamically by php. so, check boxes also will get repeated as per count of items but, now i want to display the another input field for only selected items using checkbox in table. I got the result but only half because if one item selected by checkbox all the remaining item input fields are displaying instead of only selected item.because i am changing .show() and .hide() method using jquery but how can i show input field for only selected items....
below is code

```
html table code
----------
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>S.No</th>
                                            <th>Item</th>
                                            <th>Category</th>
                                            <th>Select</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>coffee</td>
                                            <td>Drinks</td>
                                            <td>
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="itemid" value="1" id='item'  class="check">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="form-group cost-box">
                                                <div class="form-line">
                                                    <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Quantity" />
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>Milk shake</td>
                                            <td>Drinks</td>
                                            <td>
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="itemid" value="2" id='item'  class="check">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="form-group cost-box">
                                                <div class="form-line">
                                                    <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Quantity" />
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>Banana</td>
                                            <td>Fruit</td>
                                            <td>
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="itemid" value="3" id='item'  class="check">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="form-group cost-box">
                                                <div class="form-line">
                                                    <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Quantity" />
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>


----------
jquery code

$(".cost-box").hide();
$("#item").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".cost-box").show();
    } else {
        $(".cost-box").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to fix your invalid HTML first of all - IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Bro i know that but hence the select boxes are not rendered statically to give unique id's hence only one select box with same id will be repeatedly renders right.....

Comment: _"Bro i know that"_ - well then _fix it_, instead of making up excuses!

Comment: Cool bro i am not fighting with you just asking come on cheer up...

Comment: You know that id's must be unique. To make id's unique in this case, you can just add id of the element to the end of the id attribute. For example, id's of elements must be `item1`, `item2` etc. Or you can use classes instead of Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `class` instead of `id` because you used more than one time, then found `.cost-box` by `parent()` `siblings()`

```js
$(".cost-box").hide();
$(".item").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".cost-box").show();
  } else {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".cost-box").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>coffee</td>
      <td>Drinks</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="itemid" value="1" class="check item">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-group cost-box">
              <div class="form-line">
                <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Quantity" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Milk shake</td>
      <td>Drinks</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="itemid" value="1" class="check item">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-group cost-box">
              <div class="form-line">
                <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Quantity" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Fruit</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="itemid" value="1" class="check item">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-group cost-box">
              <div class="form-line">
                <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Quantity" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @naniraju Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must have unique Ids.

Secondly, you will have to change the function to show only the corrensponding elements. Try below code for reference

```
$(".cost-box").hide();
$("#item").click(function() {
  $(".cost-box").hide();
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).parents().eq(1).find(".cost-box").show();
  }
});
```